# Sibelius and Guitar VST problem

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, sheet-music, sibelius

I have the latest Sibelius and I have one VST plugin for guitar. Now I have a song that use drums, piano, guitar. Now to activate the VST guitar plugin I need to go to play setup and here say Sibelius sounds add the vst plugin and save as to change the configuration. Now the problem is when I make a orestes with sibelius sounds and the VST plugin apron the music sheet, the drums (that have notation of drums) sounds like a guitar the rest is ok but the drums are converted to guitar and I want to the drums to be drums. If I return to just sibelius sounds everything works perfectly, and the drums back to life again.

Anyone knows how to use VST plugins but without 8nvading the sibelius sounds. Or maybe a way to call the VST maybe without make through a preset, like I mentioned before?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've figured it out yet, but you need to set the sounds in the main mixer window. As seen in the image below, click on the middle black box (the one below the midi channel) and set it to Sibelius Sounds and go to the other channels and set them the same way. Make sure the Guitar channel is set to use the Guitar VST (see the white arrows in the image below).

[image: Sibelius 8.7 Mixer Window]

These settings are save only to the current score so you'll need to do the same thing for every new score you create.